# Как протестировать скорость работы и затраты памяти?

Tags: юнит-тесты, java, junit

Я начинаю осваивать Java, так что без рук). 
Мне нужно на простой программе протестировать скорость роботы и затраты памяти. 
Как в Java можно это сделать?

```
import java.io.*;
class SearchPhrase {

// walk to root way
public void walk(String path, String whatFind) throws IOException {

    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    for (File titleName : list) {
        if (titleName.isDirectory()) {
            walk(titleName.getAbsolutePath(), whatFind);
        } else {
            if (read(titleName.getAbsolutePath()).contains(whatFind)) {
                System.out.println("File: " + titleName.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}

// Read file as one line
public static String read(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder strBuider = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                fileName)));
        String strInput;
        while ((strInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
            strBuider.append(strInput);
            strBuider.append("\n");
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strBuider.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SearchPhrase example = new SearchPhrase();

    try {
        example.walk("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\Java", "programmed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В чем выражается скорость работы? Какие затраты памяти вас интересуют? 

С метриками определитесь для начала. Тогда будет понятно с какой стороны подходить к решению задачи.

И вообще, вы уверены, что ваша задача состоит именно в автоматическом получении оценок? Судя по коду, нужно оценить вычислительную сложность и примерный объем памяти. И сделать это можно без всякого программирования.

Comment: В подобных задачах (чтение файла) всегда встает вопрос:

Вы хотите измерить скорость работы с **новым** (еще не читавшимся) файлом или устоявшуюся в некотором окружении (много программ, читающих-пишущих файлы и в том числе тестируемый)?

Разница во времени работы программы в разных условиях будет отличаться на порядок (а то и на два).

То же с памятью. Однократный вызов (Вашей read()) или в цикле. В цикле память будет расти до некоторой величины, потом (после сборки мусора) уменьшится (но не до первоначальной). Этот процесс будет циклическим.

Comment: Такие затраты:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPerformance/article.html

Comment: с затратами времени выполнения разобрался сам, но затраты памяти не до конца понятны..

Comment: В линуксе я бы взял информацию по памяти из /proc/self/statm или /proc/self/status ([см. man 5 proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

В винде подобную информацию можно получить вызовом [GetProcessMemoryInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  из WinAPI.

Все равно ведь Вам важно, какую память с т.з. системы забирает Ваша программа и поэтому JVM со всеми загруженными jar-ами тоже надо учитывать.

Comment: Сделал попроще, уже добавил смотри выше!

Comment: [Java Performance - Memory and Runtime Analysis - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPerformance/article.html)
Все просто как в школе)

Comment: Это и есть школьный уровень.

Answer (score 1):

Это решение разработано самим автором вопроса, но он оставил его в вопросе.

Время работы программы:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SearchPhrase example = new SearchPhrase();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        example.walk("E:\\Document\\Effortless English\\Level 3", "spot");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);
   }
```

Потребление памяти:

```
 package task;
 public class SearchPhrase_PerformanceTest {

 private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

  public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
    return bytes / MEGABYTE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SearchPhrase example = new SearchPhrase();
    example.askUserPathAndWord();       

    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Run the garbage collector
    runtime.gc();
    // Calculate the used memory
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
    System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: "
        + bytesToMegabytes(memory));
  }
}
```

Все просто и понятно ;)